# Mostrar contenido HTML dentro de un Json

Tags: html, json

Quería realizar una consulta en JSON y que devolviera una estructura en HTML. El problema está que cuando voy a visualizarlo desde el navegador, me imprime por pantalla el texto del JSON en un `<H2>`. Y claro, me gustaría que me devolviera el json con la estructura. Supongo que **habrá que escapar alguna barra y algo más, pero no consigo que funcione correctamente** y se muestre tal cual el JSON por el navegador.

**Mi jSON**

```
{
  "Mipalabra":"<h2>Hola Mundo</h2>"
}
```

Lo he intentado escapar añadiendo una barra invertida, pero sigue mostrando el H2 como si fuera un HTML y no un jSON

```
 {
  "Mipalabra":"<h2>Hola Mundo<\/h2>"
}
```

Así es como se ve el json interpretado por el naveagador:

```html
{
  "Mipalabra":"<h2>Hola Mundo</h2>"
}
```

**Aclaro que no estoy usando Ajax**

Comment: Hola, esto vuelve de un AJAX?

Comment: Por favor, esita tu pregunta y agrega el código donde imprimes el texto. Se me ocurre que el problema está ahí

Comment: El codigo es a mano, ya que estoy haciendo pruebas, la manera de hacerlo correctamente es como menciona el compañero @the-breaker

La solucion es añadir::   &lt;h2>Hola Mundo&lt;/h2>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el json lo estas obteniendo con php, puedes agregar la siguiente linea al inicio antes de mostrar el json:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?>
```

De ese modo el navegador no lo interpretará como contenido html.

Otra solución simple puede ser cambiar todos los `<` por `&lt;`, el resultado te quedara de la siguiente forma:

```html
{
  "Mipalabra":"&lt;h2>Hola Mundo&lt;/h2>"
}
```

Si también quieres que se mantenga la indentación y saltos de linea puedes usar `<pre>`:

```html
<pre>
{
  "Mipalabra":"&lt;h2>Hola Mundo&lt;/h2>"
}
</pre>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias compañero, al final lo he solucionado sustituyendo < por &lt;

Comment: @Fumatamax de nada, que tengas buen día.

Answer (score 3):

Es porque cuando estas haciendo la llamada te devuelve el html mira de cambiarle el ContentType de la llamada a "application/json". De esta manera siempre te develovera el JSON. No se si estas programando en .Net o en PHP en .Net tendas que ponerle el contentype a lo que te digo en PHP devuelve el JSON tal cual con un echo.
 Si haces la llamada en AJAX, yo lo hago asi:

```
cache: false,
data: JSON.stringify(request),
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Si hace la llamada con AJAX tiene que poner: dataType: JSON en los parametros de la llamada.

Comment: En ningun momento he dicho nada de AJAX, simplemente es un json escrito a pelo.